# using layout() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm kind of newbie in R and I'm trying to figure out how to use `layout` to plot my 2 `ggplots` next to each other with the help of `multiplot` as well

Given 2 scaterplots:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p1 + geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p2 + geom_point()
```

y-axis are the same on both plots and it's of high importance to be in parallel.
How can I produce the following layout:

```
-----------------------------
|         |                 |
|         |                 |
| p1      |     p2          |
|         |                 |
|         |                 |
|         |                 |
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use `multiplot`, but you can do this with `gridExtra` and the command `grid.arrange` using a custom `layout_matrix`.  You can learn more about `grid.arrange` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html).

EDIT: I'd listen to the creator of the package and use widths.  If you get more complex later on use `layout_matrix`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(p1,p2, widths = c(1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Or simply widths=c(1,2). matrix_layout is overkill for 2 plots